# Eclipse dev in host or guest os

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, vagrant, ambari

Hi iam new to ambari/vagrant development , want to contribute towards the same . Iam using vagrant to set up my dev environment . Iam using cent os 6.4 as described here

```
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development
```

But iam bit confused as in where will i intall my eclipse and compile the source code in host machine or in vm . If it is in vm , then how can i see the gui to do development . Since i modified the vagrant file to include the following line of code .

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
vb.gui = true
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 3072] # RAM allocated to each VM
end
```

But when i reload the vm and enter the credentials as vagrant/vagrant , i only see the terminal . How can i see a proper gui of the VM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM that is produced by vagrant isn't intended to develop code on using Eclipse. It's used to test your code or to build from source. This is detailed in the [quick start guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Quick+Start+Guide). Here are two excerpts from that document stating the same.

*Using a vm to build Ambari from source*:

> Simply edit Vagrantfile to launch a VM with all the tools necessary to **build Ambari from source**.

The benefit of doing this would be that you could easily provision this VM and build ambari without a lot of overhead.

*Using a vm to test Ambari*:

> This document shows how to quickly set up a cluster using Ambari on your local machine using virtual machines.

The benefit of doing this is you have an isolated environment in which you can test the software you're developing.

The vagrant files that Ambari provides use minimal installs of centos (ie. they dont have GUI software (X) pre-installed.). In order to launch eclipse on those vms you would need to install GUI software or use x-forwarding and ssh to open a view on your host OS. But that would be incredibly slow and not conducive to a good development environment.

If you want to develop using eclipse then you should install it on your host OS along with the other development tools that Ambari requires. There are instructions on how to do that in the link you posted in your original question.

Comment: correct me if iam wrong ,if i have to devlop locally then i have to mimic the whole dev envt in my host os , which i have already done in guest os . then what is the point of using vagrant. I could just install the dev envt locally and dont bother about vagrant at all . Could u please elaborate on this ?